Windows explorer's upper part of the window becomes unresponsive

Every time I open windows explorer to so something, after a couple seconds the upper part of the window (part highlighted with the red rectangle) becomes unresponsive. Unresponsive means that I cannot click it, and it doesn't respond to my cursor hovering over it (i.e. no hover animations or fade-ins)
All other parts of the window except that upper one are perfectly okay (active, responding to hovering, working perfectly fine just as normal)
After I close and open it again the cycle repeats. It works for a couple seconds to a couple minutes and then the same problem occurs.
How do I fix this?
